# SQL query to return categories and category parents

Tags: categories, sql

I have some categories which are not correctly defined.
I.e. their parents are messed up.
How can I select with SQL all categories and their parents?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
select t.name cat, p.name parent 
from wp_terms t, wp_term_taxonomy tt, wp_terms p
where tt.term_id=t.term_id and tt.parent=p.term_id
```

(this only returns categories with a parent)